# Reparametrize the curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

Reparametrize the curve

$$r(t)=\left(\frac{2}{t^2 +1{}}-1\right)\vec i+\frac{2}{t^2+1{}}\vec j$$

with respect to arc length measured from the point (1,0) in the direction of increasing t. Express the reparametrization in its simplest form.

Now my problem is after finding r' is that I get this integral and I am a bit lost on how to integrate this function.

$$s=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{4\sqrt{2}t}{t^{2}+1)^{2}}dx$$

Comment: You got your variables mixed up in the integral..

Comment: @git gud I watched my teacher solve another problem just like this. I have to use dx as a dummy variable.

Comment: The integrand function should be writen as a function of $x$.

Comment: @git gud Would you mind going into a little more detail about why that is "ok" to do? My teacher did nothing of the sort to solve the problem I have in front of me. She kept the functions in terms of "t" and used "du" as a dummy variable.

Comment: If your equality is correct, then your integral is equal to $\frac{4\sqrt{2}t}{(t^{2}+1)^{2}}\int \limits_{0}^{t}1 \mathrm dx$ which is easy to integrate. It's wrong, though. Type the example you have into the question and me, or someone else, will explain how you misinterpreted the example, or, in case you didn't, tell you the example is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think perhaps the numerator in your second term should be $2t$ instead of 2, in which case you will get

$s=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{16u^2}{(u^2+1)^4}+\frac{4(1-u^2)^2}{(u^2+1)^4}} du =$
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{4+8u^2+4u^4}{(u^2+1)^4}} du =$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{4(1+u^2)^2}{(u^2+1)^4}} du=\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt\frac{4}{(u^2+1)^2} du =
\int_{0}^{t} \frac{2}{u^2+1} du$.

Now finish solving for s, and then solve for t in terms of s.